# main~ipad.storyboardc not found in bundle while archiving ipa

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

While archiving ipa file am getting error msg like

Storyboard file 'MainStoryboard~ipad.storyboardc' was not found. Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename.

I accidentally deleted the iPad storyboard again i did copy the iPhone storyboard to a folder and did drag drop to the project and modified the same to iPad

While running in simulator and device working fine when archive i get the error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by creating a new storyboard file for iPad, in previous iPad storyboard select all view controllers using ctrl+A and copy. Then paste the same in new storyboard delete the old storyboard use the new iPad storyboard